# Extract metadata from mov files on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, react-native

I'm wondering if it's possible to extract metadata as below from mov files on iOS.

Metadata I got with an online extractor:

```
content-type            application/mp4 
creation-date           2016-09-02T08:56:21Z
date                    2016-09-02T08:56:23Z 
dcterms:created         2016-09-02T08:56:21Z 
dcterms:modified        2016-09-02T08:56:23Z 
file name               IMG_0144.mov 
file size               4190689 
last-modified           2016-09-02T08:56:23Z 
last-save-date          2016-09-02T08:56:23Z
meta:creation-date      2016-09-02T08:56:21Z
meta:save-date          2016-09-02T08:56:23Z 
modified                2016-09-02T08:56:23Z 
tiff:imagelength        1080 
tiff:imagewidth         1920
xmpdm:audiosamplerate   600 
xmpdm:duration          1.88
```

Answer (score 0):

in your `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo`

write,

```
   NSLog(@"meta data : %@",info);
```

and you will get dictionary of all the metadata in your console.

example,

```
  - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {      

       NSLog(@"meta data : %@",info);

      // other code for picking media
   }
```

Comment: Thanks, I will test it.

Comment: Do I need to have a view to use this?

Comment: there is no need of view. you can get it from `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` delegate of `UIImagePicker`!!

Comment: Ok. How I should call the function in that case? Can you show an example?

Comment: refer [this tutorial](https://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-camera-iphone-app/)

Comment: I'm not really good at iOS stuff but this example also uses a view. I can't have either a view or a controller. I'm using react native and I'd like to get the metadata using a native module.